# Need help about booleans

Tags: boolean

im following Colt Steele's web developer bootcamp and im at Score Keeper exercise, but im stuck at one thing i dont really understand yet. So he set's variable of gameOver to false (var gameOver = false) and in if statement he used if(!gameOver) { ....}. What does !gameOver actually mean? I know it means not false in this case, so if not false then run the code? He then sets gameOver to true in nested if statement, so i know when gameOver sets to true then whole condition becomes true when if statement reaches it right? Which later means code will not run anymore because it reached "true"? Can someone exactly explain this to me in a bit more detail? Im confused about it, especially since its my first time seeing negation of variable's name that was set to whatever boolean especially while its in if statement. Here's the code:

```
var p1Button = document.querySelector("#p1");
var p2Button = document.getElementById("p2");
var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Display");
var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Display");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var winningScore = 5;

p1Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!gameOver) {
        p1Score++;
        if (p1Score === winningScore) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    }

});

p2Button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if (!gameOver) {
        p2Score++;
        if (p2Score === winningScore) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
    }
});
```

Comment: !gameOver is a conditional check, equating to roughly 'Is this game not over yet?' in the context of your code.  When the bool is set to 'true', the evaluation of that condition is no longer true, which means the code inside the condition brackets is no longer executed.

Answer (score 0):

`if (!gameOver)` is short for:

```
if (gameOver != true) {} // (gameOver is not true)
```

So what happens:
When you click on the button, it increased the score.
When the score is the same as the winning score `(p1Score === winningScore)`
Then gameOver is set to true and the game end.

He use `===` because this means: p1Score `must be exact the same as` winningScore.
This is because `1` and `0` are also booleans. So this could give some unexcepted result